# Trying to understand what gradle and maven actually do

Tags: java, eclipse, maven, gradle

What exactly do Gradle and Maven "do" that eclipse or sts doesn't? From what I've read it builds, runs, etc which can all be done in eclipse easily.

If I have an existing project I've created, built, and currently runs in eclipse via tomcat, what would I use gradle for?

Comment: Yes I've been doing that but can't make any sense out of what these tutorials, blogs, etc are saying. And every tutorial I've read says to not create a project in an ide. Create project folder structure separately, run gradle tasks, then import into eclipse. I don't understand what the purpose is.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Gradle and Maven are build tools. Maven was first and is a bit older, Gradle is newer and has redefined a way of how projects are built and maintained. In my opinion it's also much easier to use, more readable and easier to maintain. I prefer Gradle ;)

You use eclipse or STS (any other IDE) for development. And while You finish this process You need to provide a configured artifact (war, ear, whatever...) to production and deploy it there. These artifacts have well defined format and the application won't be run from eclipse or STS at the production environment. It's tiresome and error prone to prepare such artifacts by hand.

Gradle or Maven can take responsbility of building and preparing these artifacts (in fact such tools can do much more) off Your shoulders, they make this process automated.

Comment: So is that all its good for? If I have an existing project at home (for me, just a simple MVC/hibernate app) that I use for practicing new technologies, what/how would I use gradle for?

Comment: That's just the beginning ;) Set a test env (with JBoss for instance), download and configure gradle and prepare war artifact using it. Then deploy it to JBoss. Just have a try. Another question is how You handle dependency management? You download all the jars separately? Isn't it tiring? Gradle can do it for You! And prepare ready to import eclipse project as well..

Comment: But my project is already in eclipse, so I don't need to import it. I've tried the dependency management through the command line and that's nice, but I've never had luck running a project in eclipse once gradle is in there, even after using build eclipse.

Comment: Well, yes. You don't have to import it but imagine You need to share this project with somebody else. Adding .project and .classpth to source control is always a bad idea. And.. second developer uses IntelliJ. How can he import the project? With maven or gradle (IntelliJ recognizes both formats) this is done automatically, with all dependencies being downloaded also.

Comment: OK thanks. Is there a way to do dependency management within eclipse for an existing project using gradle?

Comment: I'm not using eclipse for everyday work but here's a good place to start: http://www.gradle.org/docs/current/userguide/eclipse_plugin.html

Answer (score 4):

Maven and Gradle can do many things that Eclipse doesn't. However, the most important thing they do, is to decouple the bulding and testing processes from the IDE you choose (i.e. Eclipse). When you work on a large environment, with many programmers, usually you can not control the IDE they use. So, it's better to use a tool like Maven and Gradle to standardize these tasks. The same happens with the code examples of a book: instead of the authors having to provide the instructions for configuring any IDE to execute them, they provide the Maven or Gradle files, so the reader can build and test them on any IDE he's using.

Another very important feature that Maven and Gradle give you, is the fact that dependencies are managed without the need of having the executable code under source version control. Instead of having the executable code you depend on as part of the project, you declare the dependencies on a text file (which is under source version control), and then get them from a repository.

However, you may only see the real advantages of using tools like Maven or Gradle (and even Jenkins or Hudson), when you think in large scale projects, developed along many months by teams composed of many developers).

Answer (score 4):

There's not a lot of benefit to using Maven or Gradle on a small project that you never share with anyone; an IDE can do the build just as well. But as the number of developers increases and the complexity of the build increases, it becomes *very* useful to separate the build instructions from the IDE. Let's drill into these a little bit.

With the increase in developers, you don't want everyone to have to come by and use your IDE to get a build done. That would be really annoying! So they're on their own machines, but then they tend to have different setups (how dare they have different user account names!) and probably have their IDE installations set up a little differently too. So we need some kind of build instructions that people can use to get things going, and it helps if everyone can use the same build instructions repeatably so that you don't get too many instances of “but it works on my machine!”. It's also very helpful if those instructions are simple enough to use that a new programmer to the team can get up to speed rapidly.

But the other thing that often happens as projects grow in scope is that their builds become more complicated. They very often gain additional dependencies (they didn't start out needing a high-performance date parser and MIME-type identifier, buit they've become required since and you don't want to have to write all those from scratch) and that means you've got to make sure that when the build is done, the *right version* of those dependencies is used. But that's not the only way that complexity increases. It's also very often the case that you find you're using more automatically-generated code. You might find yourself working with XML schemas or WSDL a lot, or maybe your using Hibernate, or Spring, or … well, there's lots of ways in which things can get complicated, OK? Getting the various steps to do all the build right, reliably, in these sorts of scenarios can be a bit tricky, but encoding them as instructions to something like Maven makes life a lot easier once you've taken the jump in the first place. (It gets even more important when you start trying to deal with projects which need many different sub-programs that work in concert; some of those are plain hard to build *even with Maven or Gradle* or any other tool.)

And then there's the possibility of offloading work to a build server, running tests automatically, managing dependencies cleanly, etc. IDEs don't handle these all that well by themselves; where they do a reasonable job of it, it's usually because they're using a tool like Maven under the covers to do the heavy lifting.

**tl;dr**
You don't have to make your code work with a build system, *but it helps if you do* and in many ways.

Comment: FWIW, I use Maven with Eclipse. They mostly work well together.